# Anchor tag behaving very strangely

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag in the website as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/..." class="abc-profileinsider-popup">
  <img src="..." />
</a>
```

The problem is that it never redirects the page to href on being clicked.

Whenever I rename the class `abc-profileinsider-popup` to `X-profileinsider-popup` where X is any string apart from `abc`, it works. Can anybody tell the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: I've added an `=` which was missing in your example in `class"abc-profileinsider-popup"`. You should make sure it's not missing in your real code though, in case you copied the code from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a javascript function somewhere that is attaching an event to elements with the class: `abc-profileinsider-popup`.

This function must be returning false meaning the link doesnt process. Try disabling javascript to confirm this, the link should work with Javascript disabled.

Then search for the code and see what its doing :)

Comment: +1: disabling javascript is a good idea to verify the hypothesis

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an event handler in your code that prevents the default behaviour, and that it's specifically attached to elements with
`abc-profileinsider-popup` class.

If that is the case you should find something like:

```
myAnchor
  .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

I would search your codebase for occurrences of the string **abc-profileinsider-popup**.

That's an article I wrote, in case you need more info about [W3C event model](https://brunoscopelliti.com/about-events/).